# Ordenar una tabla en spreadsheet, con una columna de números como referencia (externa) sin orden lógico?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Las columnas de mi tabla vienen heredadas de otras hojas y necesito que una determinada columna con un orden determinada me valga para que el resto de columnas se linken con ella. Aunque en el documento que os adjunto no es así, por simplificar, cada celda de la columna A, enlaza con una sheet diferente, cuando han terminado de "operar" todo se debe de imprimir en el orden que ha quedado en esa primera hoja, pero claro se imprime en el orden que tienen las sheet. He probado con SORT y SORTN, tanto en función como en Script y no lo he conseguido, ahora estoy intentando haciendo un bucle, pero creo que estoy lejos de hacerlo correctamente.
[Hoja](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w7nBu1GRPsTZZIuaNQiq1CvFYuB88qHGxyrpUCRXE-Q/edit#gid=0)

```
` function myFunction() {
  s.getRange(3, 7, 1, 3).clear()
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheets()[0];
  s.getRange(3, 7, 1, 3).clear()
  var celda = s.getRange(3, 1).getValue()
  for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) 
  {
    var bar = s.getRange(i, 2, 1, 3).getValues(); 
    if (celda == s.getRange(i, 2))
    {s.getRange(3, 7, 1, 3).setValues(bar);
    }
  }
}`
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor sigue el [tour], lee [ask], crea una hoja de cálculo de demostración, compártela con cualquiera que tenga el enlace para ver y agrega aquí el enlace. También explica a qué te refieres con "reformulando una tabla a base de bucles" y clarifica que tipo de solución estás buscando si una basada en fórmulas o en scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la columna de referencia no está ordenada de forma lógica SORT y SORTN no te servirán.

En una solución basada en fórmulas podrías usar `VLOOKUP` o bien combinar `MATCH` e `INDEX`.

La fórmula usando `VLOOKUP` sería

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(H3:H12;$B$3:$C$12;{1\2};FALSE))
```

Donde

- `H3:H12` es el rango con los índices para indicar el orden requerido
- `$B$3:$C$12` es el rango con los valores como están
- `{1\2}` es para indicar que debe devolver los valores de la primera y segunda columna
- `FALSE` para indicar que los datos fuente no están ordenados alfabéticamente (NOT10 debería aparcer antes de NOT2)
- `ARRAYFORMULA`  "Habilita la presentación de los valores obtenidos de una fórmula de matriz en varias filas o columnas y el uso de funciones que no sean de matriz con las matrices" (tomado del [artículo de ayuda](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=es)).

Por otro lado, en una solución basada en script (Google Apps Script / JavaScript) deberás hacer algo equivalente, pero lo primero que debes tener en mente es que debes procurar usar el menor número de llamadas a las clases y métodos de `SpreadsheetApp` pues estas son muy lentas, para lo cual seguramente tendrás que usar los métodos `getValues()` y `setValues(values)` de Class Range, que en palabras simples sería *evita usar métodos de `SpreadsheetApp` en bucles*.

Relacionado

- [Como hago para comparar las columnas A de Hoja 1 y Hoja 2 y que me inserte en la columna B de la Hoja 2 el valor de la columna B de la Hoja 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/351776/65)